# C# textbox short date format exception error, Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, date

I've been searching and trying things for little less than an hour. I don't think it should be this hard to do but for what ever reason No matter what I change I get the same error when using the monthcalander to select a date.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it some where or if it is C# being temperamental with me.

Some general description of the form controls in use - There are two text boxes (textBox3 and textBox4) two button (button5 and button6) and two monthcalendars( monthcalendar1 and 2)

When you click on either button it will show the month calendar for that button, button5->monthcalendar1, and button6->monthcalendar2: you can select a date, and it will put that date into the corresponding textBox, mc1->textBox3, mc2->textBox4

Now that you should have some details about what controls go where... This is the code I am using when a user selects a date, this is similar for both mc1 and 2, so i will likely only post the code for 1 of them....

```
private void monthCalendar2_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox4.Text = monthCalendar2.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();
        monthCalendar2.Location = new Point(306, 204);
        monthCalendar2.Visible = false; //306,204
    }
```

it stores the data in the textBox like so: m/d/yyyy,

So I have been trying to get the difference between the date stored in textBox3, and textBox4; and have tried numourous configurations of code to try to get it to work, all come back with a format exception code error when teh date for textBox4 is selected::

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var startDate = DateTime.Parse(textBox3.Text);//, "M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var endDate = DateTime.Parse(textBox4.Text);//, "M/d/yyyy"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        TimeSpan dateDiff = endDate - startDate;
        string message = "";

        if (endDate < startDate)
        {
            message = "Your departure date must be before your return date.";
        }
        else if(dateDiff.TotalDays == 0 || dateDiff.TotalDays == 1)
        {
            message = "Only planning one day of travel, please select one of the other options or select a longer period of travel.";
        }
        else if(dateDiff.TotalDays >= 7)
        {
            message = "Traveling less than or equal to seven days is not enough, select another option or a longer travel period.";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Have a wonderful trip!";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(message, "Trip Notice");

    }
```

I have tried to use:

```
DateTime startDate, endDate;
startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox3.Text,"M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox4.Text,"M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That too didn't work, so  I tried::

```
DateTime startDate, endDate;
startDate = Convert.toDateTime(textBox3.Text); //did the same for textBox4
```

It didn't work either. I'm at a complete loss, and most of these posts here are having me run in circles. Please help.

Comment: In order to be successful using `DateTime.ParseExact()` to convert a string to a `DateTime`, the input string must exactly match the format specified by the format string used.

Comment: Instead of using ToShortDateString() you could use ToString() and specify the formatting so you are certain it will be the same when parsing it.
ToShortDateString is culture dependant.

Comment: @Etienne - I thank you, I was able to change the formatting of the value going into the textBoxes to the one I saw the most "MM-dd-yyyy", I also went back to the Parse exact and changed the date formats there to that I set the toString() to and sadly i got the same response... still saying that the String was not recognized as a valid DateTime....

Comment: Have you debugged before the parse to check what the value of the string is ?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing exception for you? can you please pin-point the same? I ran your whole code written inside `monthCalendar1_DateChanged` method and it runs flawlessly for me. Is it this - `var endDate = DateTime.Parse(textBox4.Text)` line of code which causes exception?

Comment: Also please add the exception message that you getting to make it more clear.

Comment: @Etienne  -  I have been - It seems to be calling one method before text box 4 is filled like Rufus L posted below, changed gets called first ... which presents a problem... I think I can move my code in the datechanged to the mc2 date selected and that may fix the issue... let me try that out.

Comment: @RBT Line 4 of first code example :: the excetion is a formatting exception -> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" is the error message ...

Comment: I got it working mostly - its now doing the logic as it wasnt before so Im happy, Thank you guys for your time and walking me through my issue... :) 

The solution was to move the code from the datechanged to date selected... I'll be marking Rufus L as a solution.

Comment: No problem, if you had been debugging before the parseExact you would have seen that the textbox value was empty and you would have had better info as to what the problem was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely because `DateChanged` is called before `DateSelected`, and your `Text` property is empty. This should work:

```
private void monthCalendar2_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    // Update the text in TextBox4 first...
    textBox4.Text = monthCalendar2.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();

    var startDate = DateTime.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    var endDate = DateTime.Parse(textBox4.Text);

    // Rest of the code omitted...
```

I think there's other problems with the logic of your code, but see if this works.

---

P.S. This is the other logic problem...you are using "greater than or equal to" instead of "less than or equal to"...

```
else if (dateDiff.TotalDays >= 7)
{
    message = "Traveling less than or equal to seven days is not enough, ...";
}
```

Comment: it was the exact issue - Thank you @Rufus L,

When I moved the code from the DateChanged to DateSelected the logic started working, Thank you four your help and time.

Comment: Fixed the other logic issue and tested the code - Thank you